# Symfony3 You have requested a non-existent service "validator.builder", while add FOSUserBundle

Tags: symfony, service, microkernel

I have Symfony microkernel and I am trying to add FOSUserBundle.
After going through this guide to install it https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html I got error with 'validor.builder'

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: You have requested a non-existent service "validator.builder". in /var/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php on line 754
```

> Call Stack
>
> /app_dev.php:0 Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(
>   ) .../app_dev.php:9 Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->boot(
>   ) .../Kernel.php:166
>   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->initializeContainer(
>   ) .../Kernel.php:117
>   Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->compile(
>   ) .../Kernel.php:477
>   Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\Compiler->compile(
>   ) .../ContainerBuilder.php:528
>   FOS\UserBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler\ValidationPass->process(
>   ) .../Compiler.php:104
>   Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->getDefinition(
>   ) .../ValidationPass.php:41

It seams that symfony can not find service validator.builder, which goes with symfony FrameworkBundle.
Does anyone has suggestions where is the problem and what is missing?
Thanks!

**Composer.json:**

```
{
    "require": {
        "symfony/symfony": "^3.1",
        "symfony/security": "^3.1",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.0",
        "twig/twig": "^1.28",
        "alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter": "^1.0",
        "ext-mongo": "*",
        "mongodb/mongodb": "^1.0",
        "doctrine/mongodb-odm": "^1.1",
        "doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle": "^3.2",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0@dev",
        "symfony/validator": "^3.1"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "": "src/"
        }
    } }
```

**App_dev.php**

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

require __DIR__.'/../app/AppKernel.php';

$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

**AppKernel.php**

```
<?php

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Kernel\MicroKernelTrait;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollectionBuilder;

// require Composer's autoloader
$loader = require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    use MicroKernelTrait;

    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = array(
            new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
            new DebatesBundle\DebatesBundle(),
            new Doctrine\Bundle\MongoDBBundle\DoctrineMongoDBBundle(),
            new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
            new Exten\FOSUserBundle\ExtenFOSUserBundle()
        );

        if ($this->getEnvironment() == 'dev') {
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
            $bundles[] = new \Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle();
        }

        return $bundles;
    }

    protected function configureContainer(ContainerBuilder $c, LoaderInterface $loader)
    {
        $loader->load(__DIR__ . '/config/config.yml');
        $loader->load(__DIR__.'/config/parameters.'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');

        // configure WebProfilerBundle only if the bundle is enabled
        if (isset($this->bundles['WebProfilerBundle'])) {
            $c->loadFromExtension('web_profiler', array(
                'toolbar' => true,
                'intercept_redirects' => false,
            ));
        }

        $loader->load(__DIR__.'/config/services.yml');
    }

    protected function configureRoutes(RouteCollectionBuilder $routes)
    {

        $routes->import(__DIR__ . '/../src/DebatesBundle/Routes/routes.yml', '/', 'yaml');
        $routes->import('@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml', '/');

        // import the WebProfilerRoutes, only if the bundle is enabled
        if (isset($this->bundles['WebProfilerBundle'])) {
            $routes->import('@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/wdt.xml', '/_wdt');
            $routes->import('@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/profiler.xml', '/_profiler');
        }
    }

    // optional, to use the standard Symfony cache directory
    public function getCacheDir()
    {
        return __DIR__ . '/cache/' .$this->getEnvironment();
    }

    // optional, to use the standard Symfony logs directory
    public function getLogDir()
    {
        return __DIR__ . '/logs';
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of Symfony are you using? Can you post your composer.json?

Comment: I am trying to build framework with MicroKernel, like in advance example in this page http://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/micro_kernel_trait.html

Comment: Updated description with my composer.json file.

Comment: can I see the code for the `app_dev.php`? My suspicion is that a required bundle is not being loaded but I'd like to check

Comment: Here you go mate, updated description.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixing the error you reported is easy. Just add:

```
services:
  validator.builder:
    class: Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\ValidationBuilder
```

To your services.yml

...However this doesn't fix everything for me and leads to more problems with missing authentication services all coming from the FOS User bundle. I spent a while trying to add these service definitions but I think something is wrong deep down. The FOSUserBundle doesn't have a tagged release that supports Symfony 3 yet. You could try using `dev-master` for it in composer and see how that works, but it didn't fix it for me.

My recommendation is to first try it with a default Symfony3 app (not using the micro kernel) and if that still fails decide which you want more, Symfony3 or FOSUserBundle.

Comment: Great, what fixed it exactly?

Comment: I have tried from a default Symfony3, same problem there:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46217177/fosuser-on-symfon-3-3 (since this one is not about microkernel, maybe this post will reach more people)

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with
services.yml:

```
Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\ValidationBuilder:
    autowire: true
```

According to the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html).

How is it for your cases?