# FOSUser on Symfony 3.3

Tags: symfony, service, fosuserbundle, symfony-3.3

This is similar to [Symfony3 You have requested a non-existent service "validator.builder", while add FOSUserBundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40808218/symfony3-you-have-requested-a-non-existent-service-validator-builder-while-ad), on vanilla Symfon3.3 instead of microkernel (in case that makes differences).

### Problem:

I have a problem trying to set up FOSUser (v.2) on a Symfony 3.3:

```
[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\AutowiringFailedException]
Cannot autowire service "validator.builder": argument "$node" of method
"Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\ValidationBuilder::__construct()"
references class Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\NodeDefinition"
but no such service exists.
```

Browsing through online API:

- [ValidationBuilder](http://api.symfony.com/3.3/Symfony/Component/Config/Definition/Builder/ValidationBuilder.html) is marked up to the 3.2 branch, although exists in [github](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3.3/src/Symfony/Component/Config/Definition/Builder/ValidationBuilder.php)
- [NodeDefinition](http://api.symfony.com/3.3/Symfony/Component/Config/Definition/Builder/NodeDefinition.html) is also marked up to v3.2, although exists in [github](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/080cb5b5c2b27ed65a453b43fd1dd7e0d6aa3a7a/src/Symfony/Component/Config/Definition/Builder/NodeBuilder.php)

Does that mean that their documentation is not up to date with the master 3.3?

Or not maintained anymore?

### Context:

Following the [official documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html), I first faced these problems:

1. mailer_user cannot be null ; solved by editing parameters.yml:
       parameters:
           mailer_user: "me@example.com"
2. [non-existent-service-validator-builder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40828931/2375207) ; solved by declaring service `validator.builder`
3. [non existent parameter kernel secret](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24562705/2375207) ; solved by duplicating a line in parameters.yml:

   ```
   parameters:
       secret: <-generated-upon-install->
       kernel.secret: <-duplicated-line->
   ```

I suppose there is a nice and clever way to get out of this problem, if anyone faced it yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! In service.yml, do not declare service as

```
validator.builder:
    class: Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\ValidationBuilder
```

But this way:

```
Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\ValidationBuilder:
    autowire: true
```

Once again, [the official documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html) had the answer!